# No module named 'pandas.core.internals.managers'; 'pandas.core.internals' is not a package in Anaconda

Tags: python, pickle

Trying to read a pickle file and store the data in an array. I keep running into an error with Pandas package, although my current Pandas is the latest version at 25.2. My python package is also at version 3.6.9.

I updated Pandas in the Anaconda Environment to 25.2 as other links have suggested doing, but still run into the same problem.

```
import pickle

file = open('sample.pkl', 'rb')
data = pickle.load(file)
```

No module named 'pandas.core.internals.managers'; 'pandas.core.internals' is not a package

Comment: Are you running your code inside the anaconda environment?

Comment: Yes I created an environment in Anaconda, and am running the code in a Jupyter Notebook file.

Answer (score 1):

Update Pandas by using below command :
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pandas.

Then close the Anacond command prompt and Juyter notebook.

Open Jupyter notebook and start running code from first step onwards.